# Only select record if dates are over 90 days

Tags: ms-access

I have a query which returns the following information;

```
StockCode   BomReference    MaxOfDATE
301004           5170203    03/08/2009
301006           5109191    13/06/2014
301006           5109192    13/06/2014
301006           5109193    13/06/2014
301006           5109200    17/06/2014
301006           5112140    30/04/2014
301006           5112141    19/01/2010
301006           5112142    23/02/2010
301006           5112345    08/06/2012
301006           5121001    
301006           5121002    
301007           5108114    20/12/2010
301008           5102437    03/06/2014
```

I want to return StockCode,BomReference where the Max Date is over 90 days from today.
If there is a record that has a date under 90 days from today then I don't want the query to return that StockCode or any associate bomreference's/dates.

The results i'd expect from this query are;

```
 StockCode  BomReference    MaxOfDATE
301004           5170203    03/08/2009  
301007           5108114    20/12/2010
```

Any advise would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
*select * from YOUR_TABLE
where datediff("d",maxOfDATE,now()) < 90*
```

**Update:** 
I understand better your question after the first comment. Do like that:

```
select * from YOUR_TABLE 
where stockCode not in 
    (select stockCode  
     from YOUR_TABLE
     where datediff("d",maxOfDATE,now()) < 90)
```

Comment: But this returns records for 301006? I want to to leave out StockCodes if any of its associated records are under 90 days ago.

Comment: Just running the query now. I'll let you know how i get on when i eventually finish